# Как спарсить ЗАЩИЩЕННУЮ ссылку?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, парсер, url

Делаю парсинг одного сайта. Хочу вывести одну ссылку оттуда, но выводится не ссылка а `class="url_protected"`, что означает "защищенная ссылка". То есть при просмотре кода эта ссылка доступна, а при парсинге нет. Можно ли вообще вынуть эту ссылку оттуда и как?

**Вот код из сайта, мне нужна ссылка из data-url:**

```html
<a class="" data-url="https://cdn8.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/Sontry%20-%20%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%20%28192kbps%29.mp3" data-key="6918073254"></a>
```

**Код из программы:**

```html
<a class="url_protected" data-key="6918073254" data-url="#MTkya2cHM9wcmV5tcDM=6aHR0cnklMjAtJTIwJUQwJTk0Tb2LzE52JwcyUyOS54JUQxJTgxJUQwJUIxJUQwJUIwJUQwJUJCJUQwJUIwJUQwJUJEJUQxJTgxJTIwJTI4LnNlZm9Ly0JUQwJUI44My9maWxlcy9uLnByby9jZG" onclick="return false;"></a>
```

**Если что, вот ссылка на сам сайт:** [ru.sefon.cc/news](https://ru.sefon.cc/news/)

Comment: Очевидно, что ссылка каким-то образом зашифрована. Вам надо попробовать стандартное что нибудь (тот же base64). И поискать в прилетающих js метод, расшифровывающий эти данные. Ну и отреверинженерить найденное. зы: очень похоже что там таки base64, но с переставленными местами кусками

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Можно найти код дешифровки ссылки среди [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) кода и повторить его на [python](/questions/tagged/python). Или использовать парсер с поддержкой движка [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) (за этим смотрите в **PPS** и **PPPS** под ответом).

Было интересно разбираться с дешифровальщиком на сайте :)

Тут будет короткий [ответ на вопрос](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/784ee17005eb7c8b528d66c621d5eb43129a5968/html_parsing/ru_sefon_cc__news.py#L13), а после него будет подробный:

```
import base64


def decrypt_url(data: str, key: str) -> str:
    if data.startswith('#'):
        data = data[1:]

    for x in key[::-1]:
        data = x.join(reversed(data.split(x)))
    
    return base64.b64decode(data).decode('utf-8')


data_url = "#cHM5LnNlZm0JUQwJUI4aHR0cnklMjAtJTIwJUQwJTk0jZG2LzE9Tb2JwcyUyOS5Ly9wcmV2MTkya65tcDM=4JUQxJTgxJUQwJUIxJUQwJUIwJUQwJUJCJUQwJUIwJUQwJUJEJUQxJTgxJTIwJTI45My9maWxlcy9uLnByby9"
data_key = "4263589710"

url = decrypt_url(data_url, data_key)
print(url)
# https://cdn9.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/Sontry%20-%20%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
```

---

### 1. Изучая страницу сайта заметил интересное место:

```
var _0xfdee=["\x75\x72\x6C","\x64\x61\x74\x61","\x68\x72\x65\x66","\x61\x74\x74\x72","\x6B\x65\x79","\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72","\x23","\x72\x65\x76\x65\x72\x73\x65","","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E","\x66\x6F\x72\x45\x61\x63\x68","\x64\x61\x74\x61\x2D\x75\x72\x6C","\x75\x72\x6C\x5F\x70\x72\x6F\x74\x65\x63\x74\x65\x64","\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73","\x65\x61\x63\x68","\x2E\x75\x72\x6C\x5F\x70\x72\x6F\x74\x65\x63\x74\x65\x64"];
$(_0xfdee[16])[_0xfdee[15]](function(_0x130bx1,_0x130bx2){var _0x130bx3=$(_0x130bx2),_0x130bx4=_0x130bx3[_0xfdee[1]](_0xfdee[0])|| _0x130bx3[_0xfdee[3]](_0xfdee[2]),_0x130bx5=_0x130bx3[_0xfdee[1]](_0xfdee[4]).toString();_0x130bx4= _0x130bx4[_0xfdee[5]](0,1)=== _0xfdee[6]?_0x130bx4[_0xfdee[5]](1):_0x130bx4;_0x130bx5= _0x130bx5[_0xfdee[9]](_0xfdee[8])[_0xfdee[7]]();_0x130bx5[_0xfdee[11]](function(_0x130bx6){_0x130bx4= _0x130bx4[_0xfdee[9]](_0x130bx6)[_0xfdee[7]]()[_0xfdee[10]](_0x130bx6)});if(_0x130bx4){var _0x130bx7=atob(_0x130bx4);if(_0x130bx3[_0xfdee[1]](_0xfdee[0])){_0x130bx3[_0xfdee[3]](_0xfdee[12],_0x130bx7)}else {_0x130bx3[_0xfdee[3]](_0xfdee[2],_0x130bx7)}};_0x130bx3[_0xfdee[14]](_0xfdee[13])})
```

Это явная обфускация кода, а значит тут что-то спрятали от наших любопытных глаз.

Отформатируем код:

```js
var _0xfdee=[
    "\x75\x72\x6C","\x64\x61\x74\x61","\x68\x72\x65\x66","\x61\x74\x74\x72",
    "\x6B\x65\x79","\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72","\x23","\x72\x65\x76\x65\x72\x73\x65",
    "","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E","\x66\x6F\x72\x45\x61\x63\x68",
    "\x64\x61\x74\x61\x2D\x75\x72\x6C","\x75\x72\x6C\x5F\x70\x72\x6F\x74\x65\x63\x74\x65\x64","\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73","\x65\x61\x63\x68",
    "\x2E\x75\x72\x6C\x5F\x70\x72\x6F\x74\x65\x63\x74\x65\x64"
];
$(_0xfdee[16])[_0xfdee[15]](function (_0x130bx1, _0x130bx2) {
    var _0x130bx3 = $(_0x130bx2),
    _0x130bx4 = _0x130bx3[_0xfdee[1]](_0xfdee[0]) || _0x130bx3[_0xfdee[3]](_0xfdee[2]),
    _0x130bx5 = _0x130bx3[_0xfdee[1]](_0xfdee[4]).toString();
    _0x130bx4 = _0x130bx4[_0xfdee[5]](0, 1) === _0xfdee[6] ? _0x130bx4[_0xfdee[5]](1) : _0x130bx4;
    _0x130bx5 = _0x130bx5[_0xfdee[9]](_0xfdee[8])[_0xfdee[7]]();
    _0x130bx5[_0xfdee[11]](function (_0x130bx6) {
        _0x130bx4 = _0x130bx4[_0xfdee[9]](_0x130bx6)[_0xfdee[7]]()[_0xfdee[10]](_0x130bx6)
    });
    if (_0x130bx4) {
        var _0x130bx7 = atob(_0x130bx4);
        if (_0x130bx3[_0xfdee[1]](_0xfdee[0])) {
            _0x130bx3[_0xfdee[3]](_0xfdee[12], _0x130bx7)
        } else {
            _0x130bx3[_0xfdee[3]](_0xfdee[2], _0x130bx7)
        }
    };
    _0x130bx3[_0xfdee[14]](_0xfdee[13])
})
```

### 2. Сделаем понятнее массив

Достаточно было вывести строки из массива `_0xfdee` в консоли, чтобы получить понятные человеку значения:

```js
var _0xfdee = [
    "url", "data", "href", "attr", 
    "key", "substr", "#", "reverse", 
    "", "split", "join", "forEach", 
    "data-url", "url_protected", "removeClass", "each", 
    ".url_protected"
];
```

### 3. Теперь де-обфусцируем код.

Накидал скрипт на питоне:

```
import re

text = """
$(_0xfdee[16])[_0xfdee[15]](function (_0x130bx1, _0x130bx2) {
    var _0x130bx3 = $(_0x130bx2),
    _0x130bx4 = _0x130bx3[_0xfdee[1]](_0xfdee[0]) || _0x130bx3[_0xfdee[3]](_0xfdee[2]),
    _0x130bx5 = _0x130bx3[_0xfdee[1]](_0xfdee[4]).toString();
    _0x130bx4 = _0x130bx4[_0xfdee[5]](0, 1) === _0xfdee[6] ? _0x130bx4[_0xfdee[5]](1) : _0x130bx4;
    _0x130bx5 = _0x130bx5[_0xfdee[9]](_0xfdee[8])[_0xfdee[7]]();
    _0x130bx5[_0xfdee[11]](function (_0x130bx6) {
        _0x130bx4 = _0x130bx4[_0xfdee[9]](_0x130bx6)[_0xfdee[7]]()[_0xfdee[10]](_0x130bx6)
    });
    if (_0x130bx4) {
        var _0x130bx7 = atob(_0x130bx4);
        if (_0x130bx3[_0xfdee[1]](_0xfdee[0])) {
            _0x130bx3[_0xfdee[3]](_0xfdee[12], _0x130bx7)
        } else {
            _0x130bx3[_0xfdee[3]](_0xfdee[2], _0x130bx7)
        }
    };
    _0x130bx3[_0xfdee[14]](_0xfdee[13])
})
"""

_0xfdee = [
    "url", "data", "href", "attr",
    "key", "substr", "#", "reverse",
    "", "split", "join", "forEach",
    "data-url", "url_protected", "removeClass", "each",
    ".url_protected"
]

def on_match(m):
    i = int(m.group(1))
    return f'"{_0xfdee[i]}"'

new_text = re.sub(r'_0xfdee\[(\d+)\]', on_match, text)
print(new_text)
```

Получаем:

```js
$(".url_protected")["each"](function (_0x130bx1, _0x130bx2) {
    var _0x130bx3 = $(_0x130bx2),
    _0x130bx4 = _0x130bx3["data"]("url") || _0x130bx3["attr"]("href"),
    _0x130bx5 = _0x130bx3["data"]("key").toString();
    _0x130bx4 = _0x130bx4["substr"](0, 1) === "#" ? _0x130bx4["substr"](1) : _0x130bx4;
    _0x130bx5 = _0x130bx5["split"]("")["reverse"]();
    _0x130bx5["forEach"](function (_0x130bx6) {
        _0x130bx4 = _0x130bx4["split"](_0x130bx6)["reverse"]()["join"](_0x130bx6)
    });
    if (_0x130bx4) {
        var _0x130bx7 = atob(_0x130bx4);
        if (_0x130bx3["data"]("url")) {
            _0x130bx3["attr"]("data-url", _0x130bx7)
        } else {
            _0x130bx3["attr"]("href", _0x130bx7)
        }
    };
    _0x130bx3["removeClass"]("url_protected")
})
```

### 4. Последняя обработка кода, даем понятные имена переменным:

```js
$(".url_protected")["each"](function (i, el) {
    var el = $(el),
        data = el["data"]("url") || el["attr"]("href"),
        key = el["data"]("key").toString();
    data = data["substr"](0, 1) === "#" ? url["substr"](1) : data;
    key = key["split"]("")["reverse"]();
    key["forEach"](function (el) {
        data = data["split"](el)["reverse"]()["join"](el)
    });
    if (url) {
        var url = atob(data);
        if (el["data"]("url")) {
            el["attr"]("data-url", url)
        } else {
            el["attr"]("href", url)
        }
    };
    el["removeClass"]("url_protected")
})
```

### 5. Останется только переписать этот код на `python` :)

---

**PS.**

[Полный пример парсера:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/784ee17005eb7c8b528d66c621d5eb43129a5968/html_parsing/ru_sefon_cc__news.py#L23)

```
import base64

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def decrypt_url(data: str, key: str) -> str:
    if data.startswith('#'):
        data = data[1:]

    for x in key[::-1]:
        data = x.join(reversed(data.split(x)))

    return base64.b64decode(data).decode('utf-8')


rs = requests.get('https://ru.sefon.cc/news/')
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

for a in root.select('.url_protected'):
    data = a['data-url']
    key = a['data-key']

    url = decrypt_url(data, key)
    print(url)

# https://cdn5.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/Sontry%20-%20%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
# https://cdn5.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/Orlando%20-%20%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
# https://cdn8.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0%20%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B7%20-%20%D0%9F%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%20%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
# https://cdn1.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%26%20Andery%20Toronto%20-%20%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%8C%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
# https://cdn2.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0%20Proorok%20-%20%D0%9A%20%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
# ...
# https://cdn6.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/Viki%20Gabor%20-%20Not%20Gonna%20Get%20It%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
# https://cdn5.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%8F%20feat.%20Lazy%20Cat%20-%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
# https://cdn3.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/Delaney%20Jane%20-%20Want%20You%20Now%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
# https://cdn8.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%20%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F%20-%20%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%20%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
# https://cdn6.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/Carlie%20Hanson%20-%20Good%20Enough%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
```

---

**PPS.**

Та защита, кст, [очень просто обходится через `selenium`](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/339d96882621ba3287ea5ca0c655a9953589bfe3/html_parsing/ru_sefon_cc__news__using_selenium.py#L26):

```
import traceback

# pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


URL = 'https://ru.sefon.cc/news/'


options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.get(URL)
    print(f'Title: {driver.title!r}')

    for a in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.mp3 > .btns > a[data-url]'):
        print(a.get_attribute('data-url'))

    # https://cdn5.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/Sontry%20-%20%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
    # https://cdn5.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/Orlando%20-%20%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
    # https://cdn8.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0%20%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B7%20-%20%D0%9F%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%20%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
    # https://cdn1.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%26%20Andery%20Toronto%20-%20%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%8C%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
    # ...
    # https://cdn5.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%8F%20feat.%20Lazy%20Cat%20-%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
    # https://cdn3.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/Delaney%20Jane%20-%20Want%20You%20Now%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
    # https://cdn8.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%20%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F%20-%20%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%20%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
    # https://cdn6.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/Carlie%20Hanson%20-%20Good%20Enough%20%28192kbps%29.mp3

except:
    print(traceback.format_exc())

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

---

**PPPS.**

[А еще можно использовать модуль `requests-html`](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/12e3185c63569de1089a91772a27f1abfaeadd7b/requests_html__examples/ru_sefon_cc__news.py#L15), чтобы категорично сократить количество кода (он внутри себя использует `selenium`):

```
# pip install requests-html
from requests_html import HTMLSession


session = HTMLSession()
rs = session.get('https://ru.sefon.cc/news/')
rs.html.render()  # Без этого не будет выполнения js кода

for a in rs.html.find('.mp3 > .btns > a[data-url]'):
    print(a.attrs['data-url'])

# https://cdn5.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/Sontry%20-%20%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
# https://cdn5.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/Orlando%20-%20%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
# https://cdn8.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0%20%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B7%20-%20%D0%9F%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%20%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
# https://cdn1.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%26%20Andery%20Toronto%20-%20%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%8C%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
# https://cdn2.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0%20Proorok%20-%20%D0%9A%20%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
# ...
# https://cdn5.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%8F%20feat.%20Lazy%20Cat%20-%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
# https://cdn3.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/Delaney%20Jane%20-%20Want%20You%20Now%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
# https://cdn8.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%20%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F%20-%20%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%20%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
# https://cdn6.sefon.pro/files/prev/193/Carlie%20Hanson%20-%20Good%20Enough%20%28192kbps%29.mp3
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ от мне помог, почти. После вывода ссылок выводит ошибка:
'OSError: Unable to remove Temporary User Data'. С чем это связано? Я использовал модуль requests_html

Comment: Всё разобрался добавил `session.close()` и все заработало.

Comment: @GeekTarget, пожалуйста :)

Comment: Прям какая-то таска по CTF :)