# requests не подгружает страницу целиком python

Tags: python, парсер, requests

Get-запрос в библиотеке requests с переданными всеми заголовками (даже с кукисами) выдает ответ 200 и подгружает только основную часть страницы. Но на странице есть ещё вкладка, и запрос её не видит (хотя по сути нужна только она).

- пробовал кукисы передавать отдельной строкой
- пробовал вместе с заголовками.

Пример кода:

```
url = 'https://vprok.ru/shops?attr[address]=%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F&attr[point]=(55.755814,37.617635)&ajax=true'

headers = {'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 
           'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Accept-Language':'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
           'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=0',
           'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
           'cookie': 'cookie',
           'host' : 'vprok.ru',
           'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' : '1',
           'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.16; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0'
           }
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Наверное, та вкладка через отдельный запрос подгружается. Либо, данные для нее уже есть на странице, и вкладка рендерится через javascript

Comment: И какие варианты можно использовать?

Comment: Ответы 100500 раз давались тут уже - Selenium и другие библиотеки, эмулирующие браузер

Comment: @АлексейП, как вам написали -- selenium или другие библиотеки с движком js. Или можете попробовать разобраться как устроен сайт и обойтись requests+bs4. Я такое уже описывал, например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1163423/201445 или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1169901/201445